# Scala: lift on Array

Tags: scala, partialfunction, lifting

So I have an array and I can do:

```
myArr.lift(0)
```

...and it gives me option of the value at index 0.

So what actually is happening here? When I try to go to lift definition, IDE takes me to PartialFunction, and I see Array doesn't inherit from it.

And whats the usecase for using lift?

Comment: Well `Array` doesn't inherit anything because is a primitive all methods on `Array` are added as extension methods. - The use case of `lift` is that instead of `apply` it won't throw an exception if the index is out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for response. I get it. Lots of things happening under the hood. Seems I wont be able to learn this language ever :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that `Array` is primitive native to JVM and doesn't have any `lift` method.

However in Scala we have implicit conversions and extension methods and this is what we expect to find when we are able to call methods not defined for some type.

If you write the code in IntelliJ and use a magic shortcut [for showing implicits](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2018/07/25/intellij-scala-plugin-2018-2-advanced-implicit-support-improved-patterns-autocompletion-semantic-highlighting-scalafmt-and-more/) ([also available in metals](https://github.com/scalameta/metals-feature-requests/issues/218#issuecomment-883227887))you'll see that your code is turned into e.g (assuming array of ints):

```
wrapIntArray(myArr).lift(0)
```

where `wrapIntArray` is defined in [`scala.Predef`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/Predef$.html) (see Array to ArraySeq section) as

```
implicit def wrapIntArray(xs: Array[Int]): WrappedArray[Int] = if (xs ne null) new WrappedArray.ofInt(xs) else null
```

(in Scala 2.13 `WrappedArray` is deprecated and became aliased to `ArraySeq`).

If you are curious why it is in your scope remember that by default Scala compiler imports all definitions from the following paths:

- `scala` - to import all `scala.Int`, `scala.Char` and other primitives
- `scala.Predef` - to alias `Map` to `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, add wrappers around `Array`, let you use `println` instead of scala.Console.println, etc
- `java.lang` - to import things like `Throwable`

(I wrote "default" because you can change it with [`-Yimports`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html) but custom predef is something I wouldn't recommend if you don't have experienced devs and good documentation around).

What is the use case of `lift`? Basically all Scala collections share some common traits and [`PartialFunction`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/PartialFunction.html) is one of them:

- you can use `apply` to get the value but risking `Exception` if index/key is wrong (e.g. `vector(10)`)
- you can use `applyOrElse` to get the value or some fallback value
- you can check if there is something for key/index with `isDefinedAt` so your collection can be used for anything that expect `PartialFunction` e.g. `coll1.collect(coll2)` would map all elements of `coll1` into values of `coll2` treating values from `coll1` as keys/indices used for querying `coll2`

Reasoning is pretty simple - if you are accessing values in collection like `coll(index)` you are using it like function, but since it is not a total mapping it should be a partial function.

For `PartialFunction`s `lift` is just a nice utility to return `Option[Value]` instead of `Value` or `Exception` on `apply`, that you just got because `WrappedArray` like any other collection inherit from it.